# nsis GetTime Installation date is stored in the Windows registry

Tags: nsis

NSIS

When I install the program 
Installation date is stored in the Windows registry

```
Section
${GetTime} "" "L" $0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
; $0="01" day
; $1="04" month
; $2="2006" year
; $3="Friday" day of week name
; $4="16" hour
; $5="05" minute
; $6="50" seconds

WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\MyApp" "year" "$2"
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\MyApp" "month" "$1"
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\MyApp" "day" "$0"

${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

I do not know how to run the following command:

Read on from Registry > calculated > 30 days after the message plz updated

When you save the file to read and the program will run for 1 month from the last recorded warning

Can you please help with sample code

Sorry my English is poor

Please help me I'm amateur

Many thanks...

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you actually are trying to do. The code I posted will allow you to detect if 30 days have passed, if you need help with something else you need to explain a bit more (edit your question)

Comment: GetTime requires `!include FileFunc.nsh`. InstallDate is the registry key you need to save. 

    `WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\MyApp" "InstallDate" "$2$1$0"`

Answer (score 0):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

#support.microsoft.com/kb/188768
!define WFT_SEC 10000000
!define WFT_DAY 864000000000

var /GLOBAL installTime
var /GLOBAL expiredTime
var /GLOBAL currentTime

System::Call kernel32::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(*l.s)
System::Call kernel32::FileTimeToLocalFileTime(*ls,*l.s)
Pop $currentTime

ReadRegStr $installTime HKCU "Software\MyCompany\MyApp" "InstallTime"
${If} $installTime = 0
    StrCpy $installTime $currentTime
    WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\MyCompany\MyApp" "InstallTime" $installTime
${EndIf}

System::Int64Op ${WFT_DAY} * 30 ; You could calculate this with calc.exe if it is always 30 days
Pop $0
System::Int64Op $installTime + $0
Pop $expiredTime


DetailPrint $$currentTime=$currentTime
DetailPrint $$installTime=$installTime
DetailPrint $$expiredTime=$expiredTime
System::Int64Op $currentTime > $expiredTime
Pop $0
DetailPrint "30 days after $$installTime: $0"
```

Comment: ..and for testing, change ${WFT_DAY} * 30 to ${WFT_SEC} * 30 and wait 30 seconds before running it again for the time to expire.

Comment: Grateful Dear Anders

I've also changed the The only difference was that
Runs many times, it is still
Let me first say that I would exactly
The first installation After installing the
A file created with nsis
Windows Registry placed in the startup runs every time Windows starts
This file runs
Should
The date already stored in the Windows Registry with installer
On comparing the installation date
The last few days?
After the 30 days were compared
Update message to
Many thanks...